# Kill process on remote login

Tags: windows-7

I have a server running at home which typically has a full screen application running 24x7. However, when I remote into this machine, I'd like this process killed as it drastically impairs my ability to work with the server.

Is there any way to have this process automatically killed when a remote desktop connection is made?

The server is running Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: Why not just remote in as a different user (one that isn't running the full-screen app)?

Comment: Simple. Brilliant. Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the full-screen application is running as a certain user, then create a different user to log in from remote with.